# How to place two stack panels in grid vertically?

Tags: c#, wpf

i am placing a grid like this in a grid of 1st column

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
    <Image Source="{Binding PictureUrl}" Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1">
    <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Path=GeoLocation}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedTimeStamp}"/>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The image is placing fine. But I cannot able to see the geo location. i think it takes only 100 width based on the image so it does not appears. But i want to place the image to left. and geo location below the image to right. Can any one please help me to find the solution.. this grid is the content of the data template just for more information.

Comment: Have you tried removing the orientation part?

Comment: yes the geolocation and time stamp are placing vertically below the image but i need to place them horizontally with complete data.

Comment: You have given a row definiton try to add a column width too then you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

As @coder is saying you should probably just change the code to:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinitionsHeight="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinitionsHeight="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
    ...
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```